# SwiftUI drag gesture and contentTransition weird behaviour (jumping/stutter) when dragging

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[image]

**I'm trying to build a view which can be swiped up and down. I'm not sure why the above behaviour is occurring in my code. The text is kind of jumping/stuttering. I want the view to be draggable while the text is animating without the animation being broken. Am I doing something I'm not supposed to do?
Below is my code. Any tips would be highly appreciated.**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var offset : CGFloat = 0
    @State var time: String = "0.0"
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
      VStack {
        Spacer()
        Text(String(time)).contentTransition(.numericText())
          .onReceive(timer) { value in
            withAnimation {
              time = value.timeIntervalSince1970.minuteSecond // I have an extension for this.
            }
          }
        Spacer()
      }
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
      .background(.red)
      .offset(y: offset)
      .gesture(swipeDownGesture)
    }
}

extension ContentView {
  var swipeDownGesture: some Gesture {
    DragGesture()
      .onChanged(onDrag(value:))
      .onEnded(onSwipeDownEnded(value:))
  }

  func onDrag(value: DragGesture.Value){
      let horizontalAmount = value.translation.width
      let verticalAmount = value.translation.height
      let isHorizontalSwipe = abs(horizontalAmount) > abs(verticalAmount)
      let isSwipeDown = verticalAmount > 0
      if isHorizontalSwipe {
        let isSwipeRight = horizontalAmount > 0
        if isSwipeRight {
          // Ignore
        } else {
          // Ignore
        }
      }
      else if isSwipeDown {
        withAnimation {
          offset = value.translation.height
        }
      }
  }

  func onSwipeDownEnded(value: DragGesture.Value){
    withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 0.32, extraBounce: 0.22)) {
      offset = 0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the `contentTransition` doesn't work well in combination with changes to the position of the text on the screen.

It helps to add `.drawingGroup()` to the `Text`:

```swift
Text(String(time)).contentTransition(.numericText())
    .onReceive(timer) { value in
        // as before
    }
    .drawingGroup() // <- ADDED
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Btw how did you know this was the solution? It'll help to know how you found it :)

Comment: @Heshan Pleased to hear it helped, thanks for accepting the answer. The modifier `.drawingGroup()` works a bit like glue and is often worth a try when animations have issues. However, it can also cause side effects of its own, so usually it's best to restrict its use as much as possible.